# Find all $n$ , where $(5\cdot 3^m)+4=n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Consider all positive integers $n\ge 0$ such that $(5\cdot 3^m)+4=n^2$
>   holds for some corresponding integer $m\ge 0$.Find the sum of all such $n$.

I found that n is not a even(I proved it by contradiction). So n is an odd.But I failed to find any way after that. Somebody please help me.

Comment: what does $S$ stand for?

Comment: Why should $n$ not be even? With $S=0$, we have $n=2$. With $S=4$, $m=1$, we have $n=4$. Actually, with suitable choice of $S$ and $m$ we can obtain any $nge2$

Comment: By any chance did you mean $5$ instead of $S$?  This yields more than one solution, so it makes for a plausibly interesting question.

Comment: @Erick Wong You are absolutely right.I have done the mistake.Thankx.Now the question will be updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$5 \times 3^m=(n-2)(n+2)$$ Thus $n$ is odd and since $\gcd(n-2, n+2) \mid 4$, factors of the RHS are co-prime. Therefore, one of them is exactly $5$ and the other is $3^m$.

Comment: I had also done the same but I couldn't catch the last point.Thank You